# How to sum all values for a group (even those not in the group) in Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like this:

```
MUN  | TYPE  | LENGTH
-----|-------|--------
001  | A     | 5
001  | A     | 2
002  | A     | 3
002  | C     | 8
003  | B     | 6
```

And I want to show for each MUN all types and their lenghts like this:

```
MUN  | TYPE  | LENGTH
-----|-------|--------
001  | A     | 7
001  | B     | 0
001  | C     | 0
002  | A     | 3
002  | B     | 0
002  | C     | 8
003  | A     | 0
003  | B     | 6
003  | C     | 0
```

Note that, for example, the MUN 001 doesn´t have type B and C, but they should appear with 0 length.

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.MUN,
    A.TYPE
    SUM(A.LENGTH)
FROM
    MY_TABLE AS A
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TYPE FROM MY_TABLE) AS B ON A.TYPE = B,TYPE
GROUP BY
    A.MUN, A.TYPE
```

But should be more like a full join? I've tried to make an union of the left join and right join, with no luck.

From the beginning, I feel this query is bit nonsense and I don't have in mind any other way to achieve this.

Comment: If you need to sum values, why do you use `COUNT(A.LENGTH)`?

Comment: Why is the second instance of Mun 001 have Type A at 0 length?

Comment: Sorry those where mistakes. I had to hurry post the question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've managed to make an ugly query to do the job. This is the union of a query for each type, in my case there is only a few and it's ok, but for hundreds or thousands this is not a valid answer, so this would not be accepted.

Here is the "masterpiece":

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MUN,
    "A" AS TYPE,
    (SELECT Nz(SUM(LENGTH), 0) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MUN = T.MUN AND TYPE= 'A') AS LENGTH
FROM MY_TABLE AS T
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    MUN,
    "B" AS TYPE,
    (SELECT Nz(SUM(LENGTH), 0) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MUN = T.MUN AND TYPE= 'B') AS LENGTH
FROM MY_TABLE AS T
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    MUN,
    "C" AS TYPE,
    (SELECT Nz(SUM(LENGTH), 0) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MUN = T.MUN AND TYPE= 'C') AS LENGTH
FROM MY_TABLE AS T
```